# Comparing 2 Points - java

Tags: java

I've noticed that you can't compare 2 points like this:

```
if (pointOne == pointTwo) { }
```

I always have to do it like this:

```
if (pointOne.x == pointTwo.x && pointOne.y == pointTwo.y) { }
```

I really wonder why you can not use the first example, does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Check out the javadocs

Comment: Because references. But you *can* use `equals()`.

Comment: (Assuming you're talking about Java's standard `Point` class--it's not obvious you are. If you are, you should be *explicit* instead of making people guess your intent.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use the `equals` method of class `Point`. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

If you use == what you are actually doing is checking if the memory address of the two `Point` objects is the same.

In Java, all classes are derived from `Object`, and you can override the `equals` method, providing a convenient way of checking if in fact, two objects of the same `Object` derived class, are the same.

Comment: You should explain *why* you need to use `equals()`.

Answer (score 4):

`==` operator checks both reference pointing to the same object or not.

You should use `equals` method of `Point` object -

```
pointOne.equals(pointTwo);
```

> Determines whether or not two points are equal. Two instances of
>   Point2D are equal if the values of their x and y member fields,
>   representing their position in the coordinate space, are the same.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

Because the Point is reference, and if you need to use equals, you need to override the method equal. Java doest not support override operators like "==".

Answer (score 0):

Well this will be an object comparison.  You would be comparing memory locations if you compare using ==.

You could override and call Equals.

Comment: YUPYUP.  You're comparing two objects, which should never be done this way.  Note:  pointOne.equals(pointTwo) will work assuming equals is implemented :P

Comment: @Sachin, How do you override == ? This is just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `pointOne` and `pointTwo` are objects of some class? You cannot overload operators in java, that is why you have to compare fields.
In such cases it is a good practive to override the equals method for your class and use it this way:

```
PointOne.equals(PointTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your first example because running  `pointOne.x == pointTwo.x` compares the primitive types (int) which the == operator is capable of.

When you run `pointOne == pointTwo` you're comparing the Point object references, which they're not.

As others have said, you can use `pointOne.equals(pointTwo)`