# Using the identity operator

Tags: java, identity

Can you guys explain.. what happens if the identity operator ( == ) is used, given two object references such as:

```
    Point p1 = new Point (10,20), p2 = new Point (20,30);
       if (p1 == p2) {
          //code
}
```

Comment: It simple try to compare if two objects point to the same heap memory address

Comment: @energizer hello sorry but i didn't understand completely.. bad grammar?

Comment: Good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710455/comparing-2-points-java

Comment: If only there were some kind of application that would enable us to run Java programs, and find out the answers to such questions ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Since you compare two different objects, the identity operator will return false. The only time this operator returns true is when both sides point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares if both sides of the operator point to the same memory address.